# Question on font package for math environment

Tags: math-mode, fonts

With wich package do I typeset in the same style as the P is below:

[image]

?

This is just taken from a book and I want to adapt it.

Comment: it's just a sans serif P so \mathsf{P}  can't tell exactly which font just from that sample, but perhaps your current sans serif is Ok and you need no package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot! It works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\Omega, \mathscr{A}, \mathsf{P}
```